# Solve for complex $x$: $1^x = 2$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

> Solve for $x$: $1^x = 2$

There's one standard way through which $x = \frac{-i\ln(2)}{2n\pi}$ can easily be obtained but I was trying a different approach but getting contradictions mysteriously.

**Here's my attempt :**

[image]

Comment: The real part of $\cos(2\pi n x)+\mathrm{i}\sin(2\pi n x)$ is not $\cos(2\pi n x)$ when $x$ is non-real complex (which is the case here).

Comment: $1^x=1$ for all complex numbers $x$ (using any branch of the natural logarithm where $\ln1=0$), and the exponent rule $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ is not true for arbitrary complex exponents.

Comment: @Gary but take example of cos(2πni) which is equal to 0 , so can u please prove how your statement holds true ?

Comment: @Ash_Blanc $\cos(2\pi n\mathrm{i})=\cosh(2\pi n)\ge 1$.

Comment: @Gary yeah but $\exp(2nπ)$ will be real or not , it will depend on $\Im(x) $ right ?

Comment: Also $\cos (x + {\rm i}y) + {\rm i}\sin (x + {\rm i}y) = \mathrm{e}^{-y}(\cos x + {\rm i}\sin x)$ for real $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Here is a [video solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9wJ9YBwHXGI)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no complex number $x$ that satisfies $1^{x} = 2$ aka there is no solution. We can easily show this by the definition of the [logarithm](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Logarithm.html) ($\log_{a}\left( b^{c} \right) \equiv c \cdot \log_{a}\left( b \right)$) and using the identity $\log_{a}\left( 1 \right) = 0$ where $a \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \left\{ 0,\, 1 \right\}$:
$$
\begin{align*}
1^{x} &= 2 ~~\quad\qquad\mid\quad \log_{a}\left( \cdot \right)\\
\log_{a}\left( 1^{x} \right) &= \log_{a}\left( 2 \right)\\
x \cdot \log_{a}\left( 1 \right) &= \log_{a}\left( 2 \right)\\
x \cdot 0 &= \log_{a}\left( 2 \right) \quad\mid\quad \div 0\\
x &= \frac{\log_{a}\left( 2 \right)}{0}\\
\end{align*}
$$

We see that $x$ is undefined since division by $0$ is undefined. We also see that $1^{z} = 1$ for absolutely all $z \in \mathbb{C}$.

---

The question that arises: What went wrong in your calculation when you calculated a value for $x$ and why was the sample wrong?

In the step where you compared the real and imaginary parts of the LHS and RHS, you actually looked at the real and imaginary parts of the RHS, but not of the LHS. You assumed that $x \in \mathbb{R} \implies \cos\left( 2 \cdot n \cdot \pi \cdot x \right) \in \mathbb{R}$. But that would only be true if $x \in \mathbb{R}$, which, as shown, is not! So here is the mistake.

---

Just saying this dryly is boring, so let's have some fun:

We can also use an extension of the complex numbers, which includes the [Complex Infinity](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/ComplexInfinity.html) $\hat{\infty}$ ($\mathbb{C} \cup \left\{ \hat{\infty} \right\}$) serve. Complex infinity has the fundamental property $\hat{\infty} = \lim\limits_{z \to 0}\left[ \frac{1}{z} \right]$ (for reference see [Wolfram Functions](https://functions.wolfram.com/Constants/ComplexInfinity/09/0001/)). With this we can say, for example:
$$
\begin{align*}
\lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left[ z^{x} \right] &= 2 \quad\mid\quad \log_{a}\left( \cdot \right)\\
\log_{a}\left( \lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left[ z^{x} \right] \right) &= \log_{a}\left( 2 \right)\\
\lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left[ \log_{a}\left( z^{x} \right) \right] &= \log_{a}\left( 2 \right)\\
\lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left[ x \cdot \log_{a}\left( z \right) \right] &= \log_{a}\left( 2 \right)\\
\lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left[ x \cdot \log_{a}\left( z \right) \right] &= \log_{a}\left( 2 \right)\\
x \cdot \lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left[ \log_{a}\left( z \right) \right] &= \log_{a}\left( 2 \right) \quad\mid\quad \div\lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left[ \log_{a}\left( z \right) \right]\\\
x &= \frac{\log_{a}\left( 2 \right)}{\lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left[ \log_{a}\left( z \right) \right]}\\
x &= \lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left[ \frac{\log_{a}\left( 2 \right)}{\log_{a}\left( z \right)} \right]\\
x &= \log_{a}\left( 2 \right) \cdot \lim\limits_{z \to 1}\left[ \frac{1}{\log_{a}\left( z \right)} \right]\\
x &= \log_{a}\left( 2 \right) \cdot \lim\limits_{z \to 0}\left[ \frac{1}{z} \right]\\
x &= \log_{a}\left( 2 \right) \cdot \hat{\infty}\\
\end{align*}
$$

And this is kinda cool.